# Is there a way to manipulate a hyperbola like $\frac{x^2 - 4}{x^2 + 4}$ into a readily sketch-able form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

$\frac{2x}{2x-1}$ cannot be sketched but can be manipulated into  $\frac{2x-1+1}{2x-1}= 1+\frac{1}{2x-1}$ which can be easily sketched.However, is there a way to to this when situations like $\frac{x^2 - 4}{x^2 + 4}$ occur? The only method I know is the lengthy process of y and x int, asymptotes via limits, domain and range, odd or even etc.

Comment: To be clear: $y=\frac{x^2-4}{x^2+4}$ is not a hyperbola. You can (and should) examine the graph's $x$- and $y$-intercepts, asymptotes via limits, domain and range, odd- and even-ness, etc, while sketching a graph. (Calculus gives you even more characteristics to consider, such as intervals of rising and falling or of concave up- and down-ness.) However, [as @Andrei's answer shows](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3884064/409) you should not be expecting the end result to resemble a hyperbola.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you do the same procedure:
$$\frac{x^2-4}{x^2+4}=1-\frac8{x^2+4}$$
The last term is a Lorentzian function. So this will be like a horizontal line at $y=1$, but has a dip around $0$ to $y=-1$.

[image]